# DGAs with pointwise Multiplication

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, cohomology, differential-graded-algebras

The singular cochain complex of a space can be equipped with another product, the pointwise product of two cochains 
\[\odot: C^n \otimes C^n\rightarrow C^n \qquad \Psi_1 \odot \Psi_2 (f:\Delta^n\rightarrow X) :=\Psi_1(f)\cdot \Psi_2(f)\]

Clearly there have to be certain compatibilities between $\cup,\odot$ and the boundary map $d$. Clearly any DGA-map $C^*(X)\rightarrow C^*(Y)$ which is induced by a map of spaces is also compatible with $\odot$. My hope is that one could create a category of DGAs with $\odot$.

**Question:** Has this already been done or is this pointless ? Maybe this additional structure is equivalent to other additional structure ? 
(The example below might suggest connections to $\cup_1$-Products).

*Motivation:* I was looking at the group $G=(\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$ and let us fix a basepoint in $BG$. Then let us call a singular simplex in $BG$ normalized, if all vertices get mapped to the basepoint. To such an $n$-simplex we can associate the sequence of group elements $g_1,\ldots,g_n$, where $g_i$ is the group element in the fundamental group represented by the edge from the $i-1$-st vertex to the $i$-th vertex.

The normalized singular cochain complex has as basis all normalized simplices and the normalized cochain complex $C^*$ is its dual.
Then the following sub-DGA is quite interesting: Let us look at all cochains whose value on a simplex $f$ only depends on that sequence of group elements and who vanish on tuples $(g_1,\ldots,g_n)$ where at least one $g_i$ is the neutral element.

For $\mathbb{Z}/2^2$ and if we work with $\mathbb{F}_2$-coefficients, that sub-DGA $A^*$ is $\mathbb{\mathbb{F}_2}\{a,b,c\}$ (noncummutative polynomials), where all generators sit in degree $1$ and where $0=da=db$ and  $dc=ab+ba$.
Here $a,b \in C^1$ correspond are the projections $\mathbb{Z}/2^2\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$ and $c=a\odot b$.

The DGA-Map $A^*\rightarrow A^*/(a,b,c^2)=:D^*$ bothered me quite a bit, but this map can never be induced by a map of spaces, since $a,b$ are send to zero, but $a\odot b$ is not send to zero.

To add further motivation let us compare spaces to $DG$-algebras. To speficy a $G$-principal bundle over a space $X$, we just need a cohomology class in $H^1(X;G)=H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$.

To specify a DGA-map $A^*$ into some other DGA we just have to choose the images of $a,b,c$. If it happens that this other DGA is concentrated in degrees $0,1$, then we can even choose those images freely, so here we have way more choices than for spaces.

If we had the additional structure of the pointwise multiplication, we could just choose the images of $a$ and $b$  (which would correspond to a represetative of the class in $H^1(X;\mathbb{F}_2)^2$) and then we are forced to send $c$ to the pointwise product.

Comment: Dear Henrik, it is worth noting that when $n=0$ the pointwise product is genuinely the cup product, and when $n=1$ it is indeed the cup-1 product. Under the formulas of McClure-Smith (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106024) I believe that, up to sign, the pointwise product of two k-cochains f and g is the cup-k product  <12121...>(f,g) they describe, at least if f and g evaluate to zero on degenerate simplices.

Comment: (To prove this one essentially shows that the only overlapping partitions of [0..k] into (k+1) subsets are {[0], [0,1], [1,2] ... [k-1,k], [k]} or a partition which will give rise to a degenerate simplex.)